# Compare timestamp to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very quick question: I want to compare the current date with the timestamp in the resultset of my query:

```
select *
from #table a
where cast(getdate()) = convert(date, a.[Timestamp])
```

I get an error however: `Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `CAST(expression AS type)`.

Comment: damn. Thanks, completely missed that

Answer (score 0):

Your `Cast` is incorrect, because you are not casting to a datatype.

```
SELECT *
FROM #table a
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, getdate()) = CONVERT(DATE, a.[Timestamp])
```